# Freeradius certs creation

Tags: debian, certificate, freeradius

I have modified ca.cnf and server.cnf. afterwards I have deleted the example certs in freeradius/certs so there are only bootstrap, ca.cnf, client.cnf, dh, inner-server.cnf, Makefile, README, server.cnf and xpextentions in that directory, as I have learned at administrator.de howto.
But when I now execute "make all", the creation of client.crt tells me, there is still an existing certificate. I can nowhere find that certificate because I have deleted all example certs as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

`make destroycerts` should tidy up all existing certificates.

Without knowing the version of FreeRADIUS and the exact output it's hard to know if to suggest anything else. If in doubt just copy the whole `certs/` directory from a clean FreeRADIUS source, modify the .cnf files as required, and run make again.